# Set Operations On Domains?

Tags: python, math, set

I'm working on a project that involves a concept of domains similar to those in mathematics with the caveat that they behave like sets in the sense that a domain defined as such:

```
d1 = Domain((4, 6))
```

Could be subtracted from another domain:

```
d2 = Domain((0, 10))
```

And result in a bisected domain:

```
assert (d2 - d1) == Domain((0, 4), (6, 10))
```

Is there a standard Python library for these kinds of operations and concepts? I've created my own tool, but I do have tentative intentions to employ it in production code, so an optimized, and bug-free alternative would be preferable if no standard one exists.

Comment: You might want to look at [SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I feel like my request for a library with sets for mathematical domains and my brief example of a possible operation got the point across. While I had written a tool to accomplish this already, I really just wanted to know whether a production ready one already existed - I have since edited to specify a preference for the standard libraries though.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your specific problem, an [`IntervalTree`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree) sounds like it could be a useful data structure for you:

```
>>> from intervaltree import Interval, IntervalTree
>>> d1 = Interval(4, 6)
>>> d2 = Interval(0, 10)
>>> dt = IntervalTree([d2])
>>> dt.chop(*d1)
>>> dt
IntervalTree([Interval(0, 4), Interval(6, 10)])
```

Answer (score -1):

SymPy as suggested by [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112). There are other general solutions out there for orderable objects (e.g. Datetime objects) but my preference was for a standard library tool (this was only implicitly stated in the original question statement)